# Poner imagen en cada sección de mi canvas

Tags: javascript, html5

quería preguntar la forma para poner una imagen de mi galería en cada uno de los sectores de mi ruleta (como si fuera para un sorteo de móviles), lo único que encuentro es para una imagen fija (no una imagen por sector) o que el sector entero sea la imagen de fondo (cosa que quiero evitar).

De momento tengo todo el código del canvas, aquí os lo dejo, sólo me falta lo que os he comentado de las imágenes, gracias de antemano!

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
        $("#btn").prop( "disabled", true );
    });
    var miRuleta= new Winwheel({
        'numSegments': 5,
        'outerRadius': 170,
        'segments':[
            { 'fillStyle': '#f1c40f', 'text': 'iPhone X' },
            { 'fillStyle': '#2ecc71', 'text': 'Samsung S9' },
            { 'fillStyle': '#e67e22', 'text': 'Huawei p10' },
            { 'fillStyle': '#e74c3c', 'text': 'LG V30s' },
            { 'fillStyle': '#8e44ad', 'text': 'ZTE Axon M' },
        ],
        'animation': {
            'type': 'spinToStop',
            'duration': 5,
            'callbackFinished': 'Mensaje()',
            'callbackAfter': 'dibujarIndicador()'
        }
    });

    function Mensaje() {
        var SegmentoSeleccionado = miRuleta.getIndicatedSegment();
        alert("Tu premio es: " + SegmentoSeleccionado.text + "!");
        miRuleta.stopAnimation(false);
        miRuleta.rotationAngle = 0;
        miRuleta.draw();
        dibujarIndicador();
    }
    dibujarIndicador();
    function dibujarIndicador() {
        var ctx = miRuleta.ctx;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'navy';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(170, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(230, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 40);
        ctx.lineTo(171, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/winwheel@1.0.1/dist/Winwheel.min.js"></script>

    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Girar" onclick="miRuleta.startAnimation();" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <canvas id='canvas' height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con el ejemplo de la web? http://dougtesting.net/winwheel/examples/one_image_per_segment

Comment: El problema es que ese ejemplo pone una imagen en cada sector a modo de fondo, yo quería más bien un fondo de algún color y encima otra capa que fuera la imagen que yo quiera, así si hago más ruletas, la imagen de fondo no se distorsiona al tener más o menos segmentos. No sé si me explico...

Comment: Pero el color de fondo ya se lo estás asignando con fillStyle, ¿no?

Comment: Exacto, pero me gustaría (si se puede) que la imagen entera del móvil que corresponde a ese sector no fuera el fondo del sector en sí, si no que tal como está ahora (el fondo de un color), poner encima una imagen suelta en ese sector, (que no sea el fondo del sector pero que esté ahí). La verdad es que no sé si se podrá, por eso pregunto jajaja

Comment: Pues visto que el plugin genera un canvas no parece que haya una solución trivial y que no pase por modificar el propio plugin.

Comment: uhmm, tiene pinta la verdad, intentaré mirar otras opciones, de todas formas muchas gracias!! :)